Minecraft crashes when loading custom dimension/biomes, due to a feature order cycle
I'm working on a custom dimension, which is very basic, and has 3 custom biomes that are essentially just features cobbled together from other biomes. However, I cannot load my testing world, as it crashes every time I enter this custom dimension, citing "Feature order cycle found". I've fixed this error before in a single-biome dimension, since there was a duplicate feature in Step 9 of generation that I just had to remove. However, I'm having trouble determining why it's crashing now, as I've triple-checked that there are no duplicate features in any of the steps of the individual biomes. The terrain generates fine when I remove all Features from the biomes, and it even generates fine when I remove all features from all biomes except for one.
Here is a link to a Google Drive folder that contains the .json files for each of the three biomes: overgrowth_forest.json, overgrowth_flush.json, and overgrowth_snowfield.json.
It also contains the dimension file: overgrowth_v1.json, and the dimension type file: lightvoid.json. I don't believe the problem lies in either of these files, since the terrain generates fine when I make modifications to only the biome files.
My question is: Why is Minecraft crashing when generating this terrain, and what do I need to change to prevent future crashes?
